# Caption spacing in longtable package

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, captions, longtable

I am using a style file that sets a particular spacing for the List of Figures (LoF) and List of Tables (LoT) in my Table of Contents. However, I am using `longtable` for all my tables, and it is changing the LoT spacing by redefining `@caption` and `@makecaption`. I am unfamiliar with the code, so I haven't been able to identify what exactly I need to change in the `longtable` code in order to achieve the spacing I want. I'd like to be able to change the spacing to `10pt`. I've tried changing the `\vskip` value from `\baselineskip` to `10pt`, but this didn't seem to do anything. I should also say that the style file that I'm currently using is very rickety, so I can't resort to the caption package without causing chaos.

```
\def\LT@caption{%
  \noalign\bgroup
    \@ifnextchar[{\egroup\LT@c@ption\@firstofone}\LT@capti@n}
\def\LT@c@ption#1[#2]#3{%
  \LT@makecaption#1\fnum@table{#3}%
  \def\@tempa{#2}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
     {\let\\\space
     \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}{#2}}}%
  \fi}
\def\LT@capti@n{%
  \@ifstar
    {\egroup\LT@c@ption\@gobble[]}%
    {\egroup\@xdblarg{\LT@c@ption\@firstofone}}}
\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
  \LT@mcol\LT@cols c{\hbox to\z@{\hss\parbox[t]\LTcapwidth{%
    \sbox\@tempboxa{#1{#2: }#3}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\hsize
      #1{#2: }#3%
    \else
      \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
    \fi
    \endgraf\vskip\baselineskip}%
  \hss}}}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583603/caption-spacing-in-longtable-package-latex?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Have you tried loading your style file after loading the `longtable` package?

Comment: The `\vskip` you found is the vertical skip between `\caption` and contents, so it has nothing to do with the LoT. The only line affecting the LoT is `\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}{#2}}}%`. Since this simply uses `\addcontentsline` I do not see how this should affect vertical spacing in the LoT. But without knowing your style file one can only guess. So for an effective answer you should post a MWE and upload your style file.